# Hidding Row when user changes entry in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide

I have a single row that turns on when any number greater than 0 is entered into specified fields on multiple worksheets.  In essence, when ever the sum across all target addresses is >0, I want this row unhidden, but hidden when that sum is =0.  A sample code section I'm using for this is:

```
If Target.Address = "$D$16" Then
   If Target.Value > 0 Then
        Activate
        Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
     End If
End If
If Target.Address = "$D$31" Then
    If Target.Value > 0 Then
        Activate
        Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
     End If
End If
If Target.Address = "$D$32" Then
    If Target.Value > 0 Then
        Activate
        Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
         End If
End If
```

I have similar code specifying different cells (but the same row 54 on "6. Local") on two other worksheets.  Everything works well, but if the user goes back because of entry errors and changes the sum of all target addresses from >0 back to =0, I can't figure out how to get row 54 to go back to hidden because of this change.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Else` statement to your `If` statements and just set the hidden to true? (i.e. `Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True`)

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can check if the `Target.address` intersect with one of your ranges and then check if the sum of the ranges is less than 0, if not the row will be visible.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xl_ranges As Range
Set xl_ranges = Range("D16,D31,D32")
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, xl_ranges)

        If Not isect Is Nothing And Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(xl_ranges) > 0 Then
            Target.Activate
            Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could use `Intersect` to check if target.range is within the expected range

Comment: I was able to get the below to work almost perfectly, but I'm pulling in from percentages, and for some reason any value below 51% won't trigger the code as being above 0.  Tried resetting the Target.Value to > 0.01, but no joy.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an earlier version that Warner posted.    `Dim xl_ranges As Range

    Set xl_ranges = Range("$D$16,$D$31,$D$32")

        If Application.Intersect(Target, xl_ranges) And Target.Value > 0.001 Then
            Target.Activate
            Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If`

Comment: Can you try using my latest answer?

Comment: Yep - give me a few.  Thank you!

Comment: This previous version wouldn't recognize values below 51%, but otherwise worked well across all the worksheets/ranges.  This current version correctly recognizes all the potential target values from 0%-100%, but will hide Row 54 if a given worksheet is changed to =0 as the last user entry even if data from the other two ranges are >0.  The three ranges I'm working with are `"E8,E9,E10,E11,E12,E22"`, `"D16,D31,D32"`, and `"D6,D27"` on three different worksheets, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've resolved it using the following code.  For each active sheet that I need to track, I altered the `Me.Range` to cover the relevant cells.  If anyone sees any issues with this solution, please let me know!  Thank you for all the help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("6. Local").Range("$C$54")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$D$6,$D$27")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Value > 0 Then
                Activate
                Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ElseIf rng1.Value > 0 Then
                Activate
                Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ElseIf rng1.Value = 0 Then
                Activate
                Sheets("6. Local").Rows("54").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
errHandler:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```